# How can I get the full command line of all the processes after doing a process walk of the snapshot?

Tags: c, winapi, process, 32bit-64bit

So, my goal is to get the full command line of all the currently running processes. Towards that what I do is take a snapshot of processes using the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` API and then do a process walk to store the `PROCESSENTRY32` type processes in an array called `process_list`:

```
BOOL GetProcessList( FILE *f, PROCESSENTRY32* process_list, int process_count)
{
  HANDLE hProcessSnap;
  HANDLE hProcess;
  PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
  DWORD dwPriorityClass;


  hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
  if( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
  {
    return( FALSE );
  }

  // Set the size of the structure before using it.
  pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

  // Retrieve information about the first process,
  // and exit if unsuccessful
  if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) )

  {
    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );          // clean the snapshot object
    return( FALSE );
  }
  // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and
  // display information about each process in turn
  int i = 0;
  do
  {
    // Retrieve the priority class.
    dwPriorityClass = 0;
    hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID );

    if( hProcess == NULL ) { }

    else
    {
      dwPriorityClass = GetPriorityClass( hProcess );
      if( !dwPriorityClass )
      CloseHandle( hProcess );
    }

    process_list[i] = pe32;
    i++;

  } while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) && i <= process_count);

  CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
  return( TRUE );
}
```

Now, is it possible to traverse this array of processes and gather the full command line of each of the processes? How can I do that?

If it is important, I will be compiling the code as a 64bit process and would need the full command line for all the processes running on the host machine.

Comment: Using WMI to query Win32_Process for the CommandLine property is best.  No great joy to do that from C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each Process ID:

1. use `OpenProcess()` to get a `HANDLE` to the process.
2. then use [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the path and filename of the process.
3. then use [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the address of the process's [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, which contains a `ProcessParameters` member containing the command-line arguments for the process (you can also get the image path from the `PEB` as well).  Use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read the contents of the `PEB`.

Have a look at the following article for more details:

[Get Process Info with NtQueryInformationProcess](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples of how to do this with NtQueryInformationProcess(), but it's ugly. WMI can be slow, but it's as simple as this:

```
        string cmdLine = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            // Searcher.Get() throws an exception if process is protected or has exited already, so this is inside a try-catch
            var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId.ToString());
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
            searcher.Dispose();

            foreach (ManagementObject item in moc) // should only be one item
            {
                cmdLine = item["CommandLine"].ToString();
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            // write an error
        }

        return cmdLine;
```