# How can I get the command-line string of a running process with Windows APIs?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Right now im using ntdll and winternl.h, but using NtQueryInformationProcess provides a faulty PBI struct

This is what I have currently

```cpp
char* handle_commandline(HANDLE h) {
  PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION* pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;
  NtQueryInformationProcess(h, ProcessBasicInformation, pbi, sizeof PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, NULL);
  UNICODE_STRING clus = pbi->PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters->CommandLine; // where debug gets the exception
  char* cpbuf = (char*)malloc(clus.Length+1);
  size_t cnv = 0;
  wcstombs_s(&cnv, cpbuf, clus.Length+1, clus.Buffer, clus.Length);
  cpbuf[clus.Length] = '\0'; // ensure nullterm
  return cpbuf;
}
```

I've tried refrencing and derefrencing but none of it works.

The program exits with an error code (found in NTSTATUS) that indicated a access violation when reading.

Debugging that code gives me this:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
pbi->PebBaseAddress was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFDF.
```

Running as admin does not seem to work either.

Comment: `NtQueryInformationProcess` returns a value. You should check it for success or failure before doing anything with `pbi`.

Comment: Also, avoid using `new`, and certainly don't use `malloc()` in C++.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945606/how-can-i-get-the-full-command-line-of-all-the-processes-after-doing-a-process-w

Comment: Pointer values in the `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure are meaningful in the target process, identified by `h` only. You cannot dereference them in the local process. You have to copy the data over first by calling [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory). If the data read contains pointer values, you have to repeat the same procedure. Once all that is done, you may wish to consider not trashing the hard-earned data with a call to `wcstombs_s`.